# Drawing a line (not chart) in Google Sheets with Code

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In a google sheet I can insert a line (via inserting a drawing).
Is it possible to do the same with google code and/or API?
Done this often in Excel but would like to move toward Google if possible.
Thanks
Dave

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no available API to insert a drawing in Google Sheets (even in Google Docs) as of the moment.

The only way to insert drawings as of the moment (as you already know) is through  <kbd>Insert</kbd>  >  <kbd>Drawing...</kbd>  > Proceed with drawing (select line) >  <kbd>Save & Close</kbd> .

<sub>A step-by-step guide with screenshots can also be seen [here](http://www.prolificoaktree.com/cloud-software/34-how-to-draw-a-straight-line-in-google-sheets).</sub>